Input values aren't saved to the database unless they are changed
I'm trying to create an edit profile page, and it mostly works. When I open the page, the text fields have the corresponding information from the database, and when I make changes and submit, the information is saved to the database.
My problem is if I don't make any changes to the input and submit it, it erases the information that was previously in that field of the database.
If no changes are made, I want the information in that field to remain the same but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Edit profile page:
const EditProfile = () => {
    const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(null);
    const userId = cookies.UserId;

      const getUser = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/user", {
            params: { userId },
          });
          setUser(response?.data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        };
      };

       useEffect(() => {
         getUser();
       }, []);

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    user_id: cookies.UserId,
    first_name: "",
    gender_identity: "",
    about: ""
  });

  let navigate = useNavigate();

      
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    console.log("submitted");
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.put("http://localhost:4000/editprofile", {
        formData,
      });
      console.log(response);
      const success = response.status === 200;
      if (success) navigate("/dashboard");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log("e", e);
    const value =
      e.target.type === "checkbox" ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;
    const name = e.target.name;

    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Nav minimal={true} setShowModal={() => {}} showModal={false} />

      <div className="onboarding">
        <h2>EDIT </h2>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <section>
            <label htmlFor="first_name">First Name</label>
            <input
              id="first_name"
              type="text"
              name="first_name"
              required={true}
               defaultValue={user?.first_name}
               key={formData.first_name}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />

            <label>Gender</label>
            <div className="multiple-input-container">
              <input
                id="man-gender-identity"
                type="radio"
                name="gender_identity"
                value="man"
                onChange={handleChange}
                checked={formData.gender_identity === "man"}
              />
              <label htmlFor="man-gender-identity">Man</label>
              <input
                id="woman-gender-identity"
                type="radio"
                name="gender_identity"
                value="woman"
                onChange={handleChange}
                checked={formData.gender_identity === "woman"}
              />
              <label htmlFor="woman-gender-identity">Woman</label>
            <label htmlFor="about">About me</label>
            <input
              id="about"
              type="text"
              name="about"
              required={true}
             
              defaultValue={user?.about}
              onChange={handleChange}
              key={formData.about}
            />
            <input type="submit" />
          </section>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

Backend
app.put('/editprofile', async (req, res) => {
    const client = new MongoClient(uri)
    const formData = req.body.formData

    try {
        await client.connect()
        const database = client.db('app-data')
        const users = database.collection('users')

        const query = {user_id: formData.user_id}

        const updateDocument = {
            $set: {
                first_name: formData.first_name,
                gender_identity: formData.gender_identity,
                about: formData.about
            },
        }

        const insertedUser = await users.updateOne(query, updateDocument)

        res.json(insertedUser)

    } finally {
        await client.close()
    }
})


Your frontend code uses the initial formData state with empty strings. Update the logic to include some sort of isDirty state so you only make the API request if there's something to update, i.e. when the formData state is updated.
Example:
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  user_id: cookies.UserId,
  first_name: "",
  gender_identity: "",
  about: ""
});

const [isDirty, setIsDirty] = useState(false);

...
      
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!isDirty) return; // <-- early return if nothing to commit

  try {
    const response = await axios.put("http://localhost:4000/editprofile", {
      formData,
    });
    const success = response.status === 200;
    if (success) navigate("/dashboard");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { name, type, checked, value } = e.target;

  setFormData((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value,
  }));
  setIsDirty(true); // <-- mark changes to commit
};

